# How can I download OSM tiles?

Tags: c#, openstreetmap

How can I download OSM tiles? I specified various request headers, but the site always returns 0 bytes.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient())
client.Headers.Add("method", "GET");
client.Headers.Add("scheme", "https");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US");
client.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua", "\"Chromium\";v=\"88\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"88\", \"; Not A Brand\";v=\"99\"");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Referer, "https://www.openstreetmap.org/");
client.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-dest", "document");
client.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-mode", "navigate");
client.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-site", "same-site");
client.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-user", "?1");
client.Headers.Add("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36");

client.DownloadData("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/0/0/0.png");
```

UPD:

```
client.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua", "\" Not A; Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"101\", \"Microsoft Edge\";v=\"101\"");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.47");
```

These values from my browser don't work either.

Comment: Please check the [tile usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/). Your user agent is wrong, this is clearly not *Mozilla*. Insert the name of your script instead. The sec-ch-ua and referer also look wrong for the same reasons.

Comment: @scai I set the values from my browser. These values don't work either. Please tell me the correct values "user-agent", "sec-ch-ua" and "referer".

Comment: Since this script is *not* your browser you shouldn't copy the user agent from your browser. Set the name of your script instead, ideally with a version number, so that your web requests can be correctly identified. Drop the sec-ch-ua and the referrer, you don't need it.

Comment: @scai this does not work.